# Apache Cordova throws syntax error when adding platform

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, ios

I've been trying to get started with Ionic Framework, and one of the steps is installing Cordova.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Which works fine. Then I have to add both the iOS and Android platforms, but when trying to I get errors:

**iOS:**

```
benedict@prometheus:/var/www/ionic/hello$ sudo cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: 33: /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Error: /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

**Android:**

```
benedict@prometheus:/var/www/ionic/hello$ sudo cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I have tried reinstalling Cordova, but to no avail. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: same exact errors for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the ios error (is that supported on linux? - it's not in the list of available platforms when you do a "cordova platform list"). Probably needs additional installation and an Apple dev certificate.

As for the Android error - you should be able to fix that:

Check your ant install is responding to "ant -version".

Have a look at this answer for setting up the required paths in Linux, and double check all your paths with a file explorer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142421

Make sure to logout/login to apply the paths.

Also check your path is what you think it is with a "echo $PATH".